# Simple C++ - Got garbage but functions is okay

Tags: c++

I am trying to make my simple strcat function for learning C++.

My functions prints okay, but my main prints garbage. What am I doing wrong?

I'm still pretty new to C++, any bit of simplification and corrections are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int strlen(char* str)
{
  int len = 0;

  for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    ++len;
  }

  return len;
}

char* strcat(char* dest, char* src)
{
    const size_t len = strlen(dest) + strlen(src);
    char cat[len];

    for (int i = 0; dest[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        cat[i] = dest[i];
    }

    for (int i = strlen(dest), j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; ++i, ++j) {
        cat[i] = src[j];
    }

    cat[len] = '\0';

    cout << "strCat " << cat << endl;
    return cat;
}

int main()
{
   char c1[100], c2[100];

   cout << "First string -> ";
   cin >> c1;

   cout << "Second string -> ";
   cin >> c2;

   cout << "Concatenated -> " << strcat(c1, c2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable, `cat` is no longer valid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: Two other problems: You forget to allocate space for the terminator, hence you have a buffer-overflow. Secondly, C++ doesn't actually have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) so the declaration of `cat` is technically illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable `cat` that goes out of scope at the end of the function. This is undefined behaviour and must be avoided.

If you are trying to recreate the normal `strcat` function, you actually just want to put `src` on the end of `dest` and then return `dest`. `strcat` doesn't allocate any memory and assumes that `dest` is big enough. This mean you don't need `cat` at all.

Note: You can return `dest` as it is a pointer that is pointing to something that has a lifetime outside of the function.

Comment: What happens if dest is not big enough for dest and src? Thanks!

Comment: You get a buffer overflow and bad things (possibly) happen. It is one of the causes of exploits in C/C++ programs. Much better not to use strcat in a C++ program, or only use it after verifying the sizes.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can ask here, but how do you check the maximum characters a char can have?

Comment: @Kevin A `char` can hold one character as maximum.